# How to Convert Tick by Tick Data to OHLC Candlestick Data with Python?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I resample my tick by tick data to get Candlesticks OHLC data.

Here's how my data looks with pandas DataFrame.

```
    Timestamp       Price
0  1626459705  278.989978
1  1626459695  279.437975
2  1626459486  279.866868
3  1626459317  280.225627
4  1626459149  280.469473
5  1626458918  280.845010
6  1626458886  282.348605
7  1626458866  281.976074
8  1626458380  280.420801
9  1626458056  280.838577
```

How can I get OHLC Candlestick data for say 1 minute by resampling with pandas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is another solution:

```
df = df.assign(Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'],unit='s')).set_index('Timestamp')
df.resample('10min')['Price'].ohlc()
```

Comment: `10min` was also used in the resampling like @Ben.T's answer.

Comment: Thanks. Why is the result of your script and of @Ben.T different? They give different OHLC data.

Comment: In my testing they were the same.

Comment: I see. Maybe I could have done some mistake in checking.

Comment: It may be possible that the `sort_index` in Ben.T's answer (that is not in mine) could be causing the difference in your real life dataset as well, but in the sample provided, our answers look to give the same result.

Comment: Nice, I did not know about ohlc in the library :)

Comment: Yeah! That's an easy method as well @Ben.T

Comment: rhug124 and @Ben.T When I try to plot chart for this dataframe with matplotlib, it doesn't plots it nicely because the df contains NaN for for some timestamps. How to fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't it rather show that OHLC were same as the last Close. This is how it should show like we can see in any platform. They show " -- " in their chart when no trade is made.

Comment: I worked out that NaN thing rhug124 and @Ben.T

Comment: `df=df.fillna(dict.fromkeys(df.columns.tolist(),df.close.ffill()))` This helps that out :)

Comment: what if there was volume info for every tick, and in resampled data for 1min the total volume for that minute should be present for every row

Answer (score 3):

one way is to convert the Timestamp column to a datetime column with `to_datetime` and `set_index` it. then select the Price column, `resample` with the frequency you want and `agg` with the different first-max-min-last.

```
nb_minutes = 10 # change to 1 for your real case
res = (
    df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='s'))
      .sort_index() # to ensure the chronological order
      ['Price'].resample(f'{nb_minutes}T') 
      .agg( {'open':'first', 'high':max, 'low':min, 'close':'last'} )
      .unstack(level=0) # to make it a dataframe
)
print(res)
                           open        high         low       close
Timestamp                                                          
2021-07-16 17:50:00  280.838577  280.838577  280.420801  280.420801
2021-07-16 18:00:00  281.976074  282.348605  280.845010  280.845010
2021-07-16 18:10:00  280.469473  280.469473  279.866868  279.866868
2021-07-16 18:20:00  279.437975  279.437975  278.989978  278.989978
```

Comment: Thanks. Why is the result of your script and of @rhug123 different? They give different OHLC data.

Comment: @TechyGuy as rhug123 said in the comments, with your sample data, same result with both methods!

Comment: what if there was volume info for every tick, and in resampled data for 1min the total volume for that minute should be present for every row